# Group by two entries, including date part, in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have this data in a collection:

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| custId |    date    | payment |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      1 | 2020-03-23 |      87 |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      2 | 2020-03-07 |      65 |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      3 | 2020-02-18 |      23 |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      1 | 2020-05-06 |      42 |
+--------+------------+---------+
|      3 | 2020-04-09 |       9 |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

So, the data looks like this in MongoDb:

```
[
  {
    "custId": 1,
    "date": "2020-03-23",
    "payment": 87
  },
  {
    "custId": 2,
    "date": "2020-03-07",
    "payment": 65
  },
  {
    "custId": 3,
    "date": "2020-02-18",
    "payment": 23
  },
  {
    "custId": 1,
    "date": "2020-05-06",
    "payment": 42
  },
  {
    "custId": 3,
    "date": "2020-04-09",
    "payment": 9
  }
]
```

Now, I'd like to get the sum of payments by customer *and* by month. In SQL, I'd run:

```sql
SELECT custId, STRFTIME(date, '%Y-%m') as month, SUM(payment) FROM table GROUP BY custId, month
```

(or something similar depending on the database)

If I wanted to group just by customer, I think it would look like:

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$custId",
      "sum": {
        "$sum": "$payment"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What I don't get is how I can group by *two* entries, and how I can extract the month of the year from the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple keys in `$group`'s `_id` field. Note that it's necessary to convert the date using [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#exp._S_toDate) into an actual Date datatype that MongoDB can work with. You might want to consider storing it as Date directly.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "custId": "$custId",
        "year-month": {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%Y-%m",
            date: {
              $toDate: "$date"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: "$payment"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Ah I see. Instead of returning two items, I get a compounded `_id` which consists itself in a dictionary. Thanks!